# Please debug SSH Proxy Command, it cannot connect remote server with multihop SSH on PuTTY

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, remote-access, putty

I would like to replicate the following `~/.ssh/config` from a working Mac setup onto a Windows PuTTY.

```
Host server01
    HostName 11.22.333.444
    Port 55555
    DynamicForward 1080
    User username
    RemoteForward        52698 localhost:52698

Host server02
    HostName work-machine-name
    ProxyCommand ssh -q server01 nc work-machine-name 22
    User username
    RemoteForward        52698 localhost:52698
```

This is the current proxy command that I have a feeling is incorrect on PuTTY:

`plink -ssh 11.22.333.444 -P 55555 -l username  -D 1080 -R 52698:127.0.0.1:52698 -nc %host:%port`

**Details:**

I'm trying to set up a multihop on PuTTY with SSH proxy so that I can use the [remote Atom](https://atom.io/packages/remote-atom) text editor on my Windows computer to do work on remote machines. Multihop means that  first I have to SSH into an intermediate machine and then log in into the final machine.

On the Mac I just start the server on Atom remote package, on a terminal run `ssh server02`, enter passwords for both logins to get into the remote machine, and run `rmate filename` to have the remote file automatically show up on the Mac Atom editor with this [rmate](https://github.com/aurora/rmate/blob/master/rmate).

Currently I'm trying to replicate everything on my Windows PuTTY. I followed [this multihop on SSH tutorial](http://mikelococo.com/2008/01/multihop-ssh/) and referred to the [plink manual](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

First I added "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY" permanently to PATH. Then I made the following settings to PuTTY, trying to replicate the ~/.ssh/config exactly:

- **Session**. Host Name: `work-machine-name`, Port: `22`
- **Connection -> Data**. Auto-login username: `username`
- **Connection -> Proxy**. Proxy type: `Local`, Proxy hostname: `11.22.333.444`, Port: `55555`, Telnet command or local proxy command: `plink -ssh 11.22.333.444 -P 55555 -l username  -D 1080 -R 52698:127.0.0.1:52698 -nc %host:%port`
- **Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels**. the window displays for remote port forwarding: `R52698      localhost:52698`

**I get a big blank black screen when I try to run everything.  I'm suspecting my ProxyCommand is not set up correctly.**

(Btw I have found X11 to be completely unnecessary through my Mac settings.)

Trying to debug, I ran the ProxyCommand plink line on the cmd prompt:

```
C:\Users\username>plink -ssh 11.22.333.444 -P 55555 -l username -D 1080 -R 52698:127.0.0.1:52698 -nc work-machine-name:22
username@11.22.333.444's password:
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
```

And it hangs there after entering the password. On the Mac, it would ask for the second password too and then be connected to the remote work-machine.

Comment: Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly helpful too.

Comment: are you able to run X11 on the first machine you SSH to? Can you check if that part is working?

Comment: Try using the concept of hop discussed in http://mikelococo.com/2008/01/multihop-ssh/. Read the putty config section

Comment: @TarunLalwani xclock didn't work on the first machine. See my edit. Do you think it might be a firewall issue due to the double log-in?

Comment: Few things you could check, does the SSH config allow X11Forwarding also check if any iptables rules for blocking are there? even ufw firewall

Comment: Do you actually have an X emulator on the Windows machine?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have updated the question with my current findings

Comment: @tink I have updated the question with my current findings

Comment: Did you enable agent forwarding also on the machine?

Comment: That's a nice bonus you've got there, but this question is off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Which stack exchange is more appropriate then?  Yeah I need to resolve this ASAP hence the bonus.

Answer (score 2):

it appears the problem you're facing is incompatability between "standard" ssh tooling and putty

some possible workarounds is to use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) ssh, [linux subsystem for windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install-win10), or [mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) (which is bassically cygwin + a better terminal emulator and embedded x11 server)

all of them work with the same configuration files format as linux and mac, so your existing config should work

Comment: Thanks. How can I test that it's incompatibility versus having the wrong command?

Comment: I believe the simplest way would be to experiment with the alternatives. I believe mobaxterm is the simplest to setup

Comment: Why would it be incompatible? Aren't PuTTY, plink, and Windows all standard stuff?

Comment: putty is standard in terms it can talk with any compliant ssh server. this doesn't mean the configuration files are in the same format as on linux.
using various ports of open ssh on windows ensures that also the configuration files and command line syntax is the same

Comment: it doesn't mean putty wont work - it's just more complicated without having an environment to troubleshoot

Comment: So basically there is nothing you'd change in `plink -ssh 11.22.333.444 -P 55555 -l username  -D 1080 -R 52698:127.0.0.1:52698 -nc %host:%port` and you think if things were compatible, this proxy line in PuTTY would be correct?

Comment: I mean that if this same line worked on Mac with ssh client, it would work on Windows with an openssh client instead of plink (any of the versions I mentioned)

Comment: Thanks Yoktan Mobaxterm works. Out of the 3 (cygwin ssh, linux subsystem for windows, or mobaxterm), what are the pros and cons of each for my case? Which one is the fastest? Which one is the most secure?
 Thanks.

Comment: the differences are mostly convenience, and suitability for other tasks
mobaxterm and cygwin are the same under the hood - mobaxterm is prepackaged and includes a more convenient terminal emulator. linux subsystem runs actual linux binaries, which is usefull if you want to run linux tools that weren't ported to windows

Answer (score 1):

These are a couple of ideas,  your use case is very particular and probably are better tools to achieve what you need, to simplify all the proxy you could probably use a VPN between your devices, but to focus on the SSH side I would suggest checking how forwarding is being done and how to test  (bastion) setup using putty.

### forwarding

What could be happening is that in your windows client, the ssh passwords are not been forwarded, something that works when doing:

```
ssh -A
```

From the man:

> -A Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

In windows when using putty to achieve something similar you need to use something call `Pageant`.

Pageant is a PuTTY authentication agent. It holds your private keys in memory so that you can use them whenever you are connecting to a server. It eliminates the need to:

- Explicitly specify the relevant key to each Linux user account, if you use more than one account to log into a server
- Type a key's passphrase each time you log into your user account; and your keys should be passphrase protected since having an unprotected key is as good as hiding your password under your keyboard!

To know more about how to configure your client follow this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pageant-to-streamline-ssh-key-authentication-with-putty

### bastion - ssh tunnel

Check this guide, https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/04/how-to-configure-an-ssh-tunnel-on-putty.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My shell plink ran into fatal connection errors when I was about to try `plink -agent`. Since Ophir's suggestion worked, I decided to not pursue further down this `plink` line. Thank you so much though.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar need, but my middle server doesn't allow netcat.
The solution I came up with is using `-W` flag for the ssh (I'm using OpenSSH), and it can be done with a similar ssh config to the one you are already using on the mac.

the default location for the ssh config on windows is - `C:\Users\$username$\.ssh\config`.

```
Host server01
    HostName 11.22.333.444
    Port 55555
    User username

Host server02
    HostName work-machine-name
    ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -W %h:%p server01
    User username
```

Two notes on the config:

- The file might not exist but you can just create it yourself, notice it has no extention.
- The `ProxyCommand` might have hard time locating the ssh.exe, so absulute path is preferable here.

If you prefer avoiding the `ssh_config` and having a command line to do that you might want to use:

`ssh -t username@11.22.33.4444 "ssh -t username@work-machine-name"`

I hope it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want **ssh** to `172.16.0.21` via `8.8.8.8`

login name in both hosts is `john`

path to private key is `C:\users\john\.ssh\private.ppk`

[image]

[image]
[image]

### .

```
plink.exe -v -ssh %user@%proxyhost -P %proxyport -nc %host:%port   -i "c:\Users\john\.ssh\private.ppk"
```